# Race Condition in CUDA Kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, race-condition

I have a CUDA kernel that appears to have race condition and am trying to pinpoint where this race condition is coming from. I am aware of the 'racecheck' tool of cuda-memcheck, however racecheck tells me that there is no hazard when using small inputs which is actually consistent with my own investigations too. For large inputs though racecheck seems to take forever (literally) and so I can't use it.
Briefly explaining, a 1D vector `d_mat_3d` defined as a `__device__` variable is filled with 0 and loaded in global memory. Two large arrays which are the inputs for the kernel (`d_A` and `d_v`) are also defined in `main` and passed to the kernal. A segment of array `d_mat_3d`, called `mat_2d` is cut, loaded in shared memory and some processing will be done on it. Then, `mat_2d` will be written back to `d_mat_3d` on global memory.

As shown here, atomic operations are used as without the use of atomic operations `mat_2d` would encounter a race condition b/w different threads.

The reason I guess I still have some sort of race condition going on is that the results of `mat_3d` is different every time.

Any thought as to where this race condition may come from? Any steps I can take to clear that out (other than the tool racecheck)? If you think, there is no evidence for race condition, can you explain why different values are assigned to `d_mat_3d` every time I execute the kernel?

CUDA 9.0 / NVidia Titan Black / Ubuntu 16.04

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define W 7              // fix limit for loops in kernel
#define SIZE 100         // defining matrix dimension
#define N_ELEM 10000     // no of elements in each vector
#define NTPB 1024        // no of threads per block

using namespace std;

__device__ float d_mat_3d[SIZE*SIZE*SIZE]; 

__global__ void cuda_kernel(float *d_A, float *d_v){

  __shared__ float mat_2d[SIZE*SIZE]; // a 2D slice of 3D matrix d_mat_3d

  unsigned int n = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;

  if(n >= N_ELEM)
    return;

  int x, y, z, i;
  float r;
  float A = d_A[n];
  float v = d_v[n];

  #pragma unroll
  for(x=0; x<SIZE; x++){

    // load mat_2d (on shared memory) using d_mat_3d (on global memory)
    for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++){
      mat_2d[i] = d_mat_3d[i+x*SIZE*SIZE];
    }

    // sync threads as mat_2d is on shared memory
    __syncthreads();

    for(y=SIZE/2; y<SIZE/2+W; y++){ 
      for(z=SIZE/2; z<SIZE/2+W; z++){
        r = sqrt( pow(A,2) / v );  // no need to be in these loops. I know, but for my real case, it must be.
        atomicAdd(&mat_2d[z+y*SIZE], r); // atomically add r 
      }
    }

    __syncthreads();
    // write mat_2d (shared memory) back to mat_3d (global memory)
    for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++){
      d_mat_3d[i+x*SIZE*SIZE] = mat_2d[i];
    }
  }
}

// this function writes h_mat_3d to disk. 
void write_image(float *h_mat_3d){
  ostringstream o_addToFile;
  o_addToFile << "mat3d.bin";
  FILE *pFile; 
  pFile = fopen(o_addToFile.str().c_str(), "wb");
  for(int i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE*SIZE; i++){ 
    fwrite(&h_mat_3d[i], sizeof(float), 1, pFile);
  }
  fclose (pFile);
}

int main(){

  int i;
  float *h_A = new float[N_ELEM]; // some large vector
  float *h_v = new float[N_ELEM]; // some other large vector
  float h_mat_3d[SIZE*SIZE*SIZE]; // will be filled w/ 0
  float *d_A; // device variables
  float *d_v;

  for(i=0; i<N_ELEM; i++){
    h_A[i] = 0.2f+(float)i/N_ELEM; // fill out with some calculations
    h_v[i] = 0.5f+2.f*i/N_ELEM;
  }
  for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE*SIZE; i++){
    h_mat_3d[i] = 0.f; // fill h_mat_3d with 0 
  }

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM); // allocate variables on device
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_v, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM);

  cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // copy from host to device
  cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_mat_3d, &h_mat_3d, sizeof(float)*SIZE*SIZE*SIZE); // copy h_mat_3d to device

  cuda_kernel<<<(N_ELEM+NTPB-1)/NTPB,NTPB>>>(d_A, d_v); // execute kernel

  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(h_mat_3d, d_mat_3d, sizeof(float)*SIZE*SIZE*SIZE); // write it back to h_mat_3d

  write_image(h_mat_3d); // write h_mat_3d to disk for checking

  cudaFree(d_A); // free memory
  cudaFree(d_v);
  delete [] h_A;
  delete [] h_v;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually for questions like this, SO expects that you provide a [mcve].  Read item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Note the usage of the word "must".  If your claims are correct, it shouldn't require many additional lines of code to build a complete program to demonstrate your claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have at least 2 different race conditions in your code.

1. Since you are loading the entirety of shared memory in a loop (i.e. loading it all, over and over again, in a loop), it's necessary to protect both the start and the end of the load operation with `__syncthreads()`.  Doing so will reduce the variability from run-to-run down to the 6th or 7th significant decimal digit, which is consistent with [ordinary `float` variability in floating-point operations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html), where the order of operations is not duplicated (which will generally be the case here).

   adding the following line:

   ```
     for(x=0; x<SIZE; x++){
       __syncthreads();  // add this line
       // load mat_2d (on shared memory) using d_mat_3d (on global memory)
       for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++){
         mat_2d[i] = d_mat_3d[i+x*SIZE*SIZE];
       }

       // sync threads as mat_2d is on shared memory
       __syncthreads();
   ```

   should mostly correct the issue.  Without that, as your kernel loops in `x`, some warps can "race ahead" to start loading shared memory, while previous warps are still busy with the previous loop iteration in `x` (and take note of comment 2 below, which probably exacerbates this issue.)
2. Since *each threadblock* is writing to the entirety of `d_mat_3d`, you have a race condition as each threadblock attempts to write various values.  The order of threadblock execution (undefined by CUDA) will mostly determine what ends up there, and this can easily vary run-to-run.  The only trivial way I know of to sort this out without a complete kernel re-write is to simply launch 1 threadblock (which will still populate the same regions of `d_mat_3d`).   This sort of race condition is a global memory race, and `cuda-memcheck` cannot discover this kind of race, currently.  I hesitate to read too much into this, but this code doesn't really make any sense, and either indicates a lack of concern for a sensible code, or a lack of understanding of the CUDA execution model (especially coupled with item 2 below.)

There are a few other things I would point out.

1. Your use of `__syncthreads()` is potentially illegal in the last threadblock.  This construct:

   ```
     if(n >= N_ELEM)
       return;
   ```

   will allow some threads in the (last) threadblock to retire early, meaning they will not participate in the subsequent `__syncthreads()` statements.  This is illegal in CUDA, and the restriction is covered in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).  This is fixable by removing the early return, and protecting the various segments of your kernel loop (except the __syncthreads() statements) with `if (n < N_ELEM)` or similar.
2. Your kernel code is generally strange, as you have pointed out in your comments already.  One example of this is that you have every thread in the block doing the exact same loads and stores to/from shared memory.  This is wasteful, performance-wise, in several ways.

I'm not suggesting this covers every issue with the code, merely the things I noticed.  Here is a relatively complete test case that I used to verify my findings.  It includes some changes to address items I mentioned above, as well as various other changes that seemed important to me:

```
$ cat t268.cu
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define W 7              // fix limit for loops in kernel
#define SIZE 100         // defining matrix dimension
#define N_ELEM 10000     // no of elements in each vector
#define NTPB 1024        // no of threads per block

using namespace std;

__device__ float d_mat_3d[SIZE*SIZE*SIZE];

__global__ void cuda_kernel(float *d_A, float *d_v){

  __shared__ float mat_2d[SIZE*SIZE]; // a 2D slice of 3D matrix d_mat_3d

  unsigned int n = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;


  int x, y, z, i;
  float r;
  float A = d_A[n];
  float v = d_v[n];

  #pragma unroll
  for(x=0; x<SIZE; x++){
  __syncthreads();
if (n < N_ELEM){
    // load mat_2d (on shared memory) using d_mat_3d (on global memory)
    for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++){
      mat_2d[i] = d_mat_3d[i+x*SIZE*SIZE];
    }
}
    // sync threads as mat_2d is on shared memory
    __syncthreads();
if (n < N_ELEM){
    for(y=SIZE/2; y<SIZE/2+W; y++){
      for(z=SIZE/2; z<SIZE/2+W; z++){
        r = sqrt( pow(A,2) / v );  // no need to be in these loops. I know, but for my real case, it must be.
        atomicAdd(&(mat_2d[z+y*SIZE]), r); // atomically add r
      }
    }
}
    __syncthreads();
    // write mat_2d (shared memory) back to mat_3d (global memory)
if (n < N_ELEM){
    for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++){
      d_mat_3d[i+x*SIZE*SIZE] = mat_2d[i];
    }
}
  }
}

// this function writes h_mat_3d to disk.
void write_image(float *h_mat_3d){
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE*SIZE; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
      if (h_mat_3d[i*SIZE+j] > 1.0f) printf("%d:%f\n ", i*SIZE+j,  h_mat_3d[i*SIZE+j]);
    printf("\n");}
}

int main(){

  int i;
  float *h_A = new float[N_ELEM]; // some large vector
  float *h_v = new float[N_ELEM]; // some other large vector
  float *h_mat_3d = new float[SIZE*SIZE*SIZE]; // will be filled w/ 0
  float *d_A; // device variables
  float *d_v;

  for(i=0; i<N_ELEM; i++){
    h_A[i] = 0.2f+i/(float)N_ELEM; // fill out with some calculations
    h_v[i] = 0.5f+2.f*i/(float)N_ELEM;
  }
  for(i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE*SIZE; i++){
    h_mat_3d[i] = 0.f; // fill h_mat_3d with 0
  }

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM); // allocate variables on device
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_v, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM);

  cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // copy from host to device
  cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, sizeof(float)*N_ELEM, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_mat_3d, h_mat_3d, sizeof(float)*SIZE*SIZE*SIZE); // copy h_mat_3d to device

  cuda_kernel<<<1,NTPB>>>(d_A, d_v); // execute kernel

  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(h_mat_3d, d_mat_3d, sizeof(float)*SIZE*SIZE*SIZE); // write it back to h_mat_3d

  write_image(h_mat_3d); // write h_mat_3d to disk for checking

  cudaFree(d_A); // free memory
  delete [] h_A;
  delete [] h_v;

  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t268 t268.cu
$ ./t268 > out1.txt
$ ./t268 > out2.txt
$ diff out1.txt out2.txt |more
51,57c51,57
< 5050:330.657715
<  5051:330.657715
<  5052:330.657715
<  5053:330.657715
<  5054:330.657715
<  5055:330.657715
<  5056:330.657715
---
> 5050:330.657654
>  5051:330.657593
>  5052:330.657593
>  5053:330.657593
>  5054:330.657593
>  5055:330.657593
>  5056:330.657593
59,65c59,65
< 5150:330.657715
<  5151:330.657715
<  5152:330.657715
<  5153:330.657715
<  5154:330.657745
<  5155:330.657745
<  5156:330.657745
---
> 5150:330.657593
>  5151:330.657593
>  5152:330.657593
>  5153:330.657593
>  5154:330.657593
>  5155:330.657593
>  5156:330.657593
67,73c67,73
< 5250:330.657745
<  5251:330.657745
<  5252:330.657745
<  5253:330.657745
<  5254:330.657715
<  5255:330.657715
<  5256:330.657715
---
> 5250:330.657593
>  5251:330.657593
>  5252:330.657623
>  5253:330.657593
>  5254:330.657593
>  5255:330.657593
>  5256:330.657593
75,81c75,81
< 5350:330.657715
<  5351:330.657715
<  5352:330.657715
<  5353:330.657715
<  5354:330.657715
<  5355:330.657745
<  5356:330.657715
---
> 5350:330.657593
>  5351:330.657593
$
```

As can be seen, the remaining variation is in the 7th significant decimal digit:

```
51,57c51,57
< 5050:330.657715
...
---
> 5050:330.657654
```

Comment: Nevertheless, each threadblock in your presented code writes the entire `d_mat_3d` array.  Since each threadblock is writing different data, this is a race condition.  I'm not suggesting that switching to a single threadblock is a sensible solution, I'm using it to demonstrate that the results variability mostly disappears when I do that, which helps to confirm that race condition (although it is obviously evident by inspection of the code).  So the simple answer is yes, you have race conditions, and I have pointed out two of them.

Comment: Beyond that, your code makes no sense, but that is a separate issue, and not the question you asked.  If your actual code is anything like your presented code in the respects I've mentioned, it's going to  need a substantial re-write.

Comment: atomic exchange won't fix it.  The order of threadblock execution will affect the order of atomic exchanges.  The last threadblock will "win", and that may vary run to run.  If you did an `atomicAdd` of all threadblock results together in the final array, that might mostly remove the variability associated with the threadblock-to-global write race.  I still claim that none of this makes any sense, and it's not really clear that you understand the execution model.  How could atomic exhange do anything useful?  You'd still be throwing away lots of calculated results, just as  you  are doing now.

Comment: I'm sure there probably is.  But I can't possibly suggest it because you've given no description of the algorithm you'd actually like to perform.  You've pretended that the code presented is a useful description of the algorithm.  I claim it is not, for the reasons already discussed.  If you want to combine the results from multiple threadblocks into a single array, you'll have to define exactly the arithmetic you want to do, and what results will go where.  If you have a new question, I suggest you ask a new question.  Let's not clutter this one up any further.